# Sonar default, meet "container state was: CONSTRUCTED"

Tags: maven-2, sonarqube

Environment: hudson/sonar/maven2 in ubuntu locally with default parameters

And I got the log from hudson below, I can't figure out where is the problem.

```
[INFO] Sonar host: http://localhost:9000
[INFO] Sonar version: 2.0.1
[INFO] [sonar-core:internal {execution: default-internal}]
[INFO]  Database dialect class org.sonar.api.database.dialect.Derby
[INFO]  -------------  Analyzing Game of Life business logic module
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Can not analyze the project
Cannot stop.  Current container state was: CONSTRUCTED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
```

And I notice it also has problem when run it command line without hudson

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

Comment: I don't how to attach here, see http://pastebin.com/x85ui2qB for the log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the hints from http://old.nabble.com/Another-%22Current-container-state-was%3A-CONSTRUCTED%22-problem-td28172925.html#a28194257

It seems the problem is inconsistency in maven plugins in my nexus repository, when I change to mirrors.ibiblio.org and clean the .m2 directory, everything goes fine.

BUT I don't know which plugins causes this problem and the log information is so wired, will be nice if some people points which plugin cause this problem and explain the reason for this error information

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem  with .Net plugins for Sonar.
They needed all projects to be analyzed with JDK 6 (even non-.Net projects).
This error was raised when I tried to analyze projects with JDK 5.

Here is the URL of the .Net plugins : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/.Net+plugin

The solution I got was to fork the compiler to use a JDK5 compiler on my projects which needed to be analyzed in JDK5 and not JDK6.

See on the .Net plugins page :

> Maven and Sonar dotnet plugins need Java6 (at compile time and runtime)

What the sentence does not say is that all projects in your Sonar instance must use Java6.
A JIRA has been created : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1086 .

Comment: You were right about the wiki. I have just updated it. You should register to sonar user mailing-list to give this king of feedback ;)